# Select fields from multiple tables and use OUTER JOIN on one table

Tags: mysql, join

My query selects multiple fields from 4 tables and I need to add OUTER JOIN or LEFT OUTER JOIN to compare values from another table.

```
SELECT *, table1.name, table2.wage, table3.shift, table4.vacation
FROM table1, table2, table3, table4 OUTER JOIN table5 ON table1.name = table5.position
WHERE table1.name = table2.name
AND table2.wage = table3.wage
```

This is just an example but how do I make it work, it seems to work if I have just one table in FROM clause.

Answer (score 2):

Use ANSI syntax for all your joins, eg

```
SELECT table1.name, table2.wage, table3.shift, table4.vacation,
  table5.someDateTimeField
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.name = table2.name
INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.wage = table3.wage
INNER JOIN table4 ON something = table4.something -- can't see this one in your example
LEFT JOIN table5 ON table1.name = table5.position
WHERE someArbitraryFilter BETWEEN 3 AND 7;
```

Also, your `SELECT` clause looks all wrong. I don't know which `*` you're after and you're missing commas

Comment: What if i need to select something else from table table5 e.g.date and time how i can make so if i need regular select not with join
also one of filters is BETWEEN 3 AND 7 how can i represent it in this query

Comment: @BUddhaxx I've updated my answer though I'm not entirely sure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Try using explicit JOIN's instead of those implicit ones:

```
SELECT table1.name, table2.wage, table3.shift, table4.vacation
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.name = table2.name
JOIN table3 ON table2.wage = table3.wage
JOIN table4 ON ??
LEFT JOIN table5 ON table1.name = table5.position
```

plus, it seems you are missing a condition for table4 join.

Comment: What if i need to select something else from table table5 e.g.date and time how i can make so if i need regular select not with join

Comment: @BUddhaxx - What do you mean not with JOIN? The joins you already have are going to return several rows - would all of them get the same value from table5?